# All combinations for $x_i+y_j$ in a finite sets of real numbers

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, real-numbers, natural-numbers, binary-operations

Consider $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\{x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n\},\{y_1, y_2, \cdots, y_m\} \subset \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$.

**Question.** How many possible combinations we can form with elements of the form $
x_i+y_j $, for $i=1,\cdots,n$ and $j=1,\cdots, m$?

In the sense that, suppose $n=2$ and $m=3$, then we would have
$$
x_1+y_1, x_1+y_2, x_1+y_3, x_2+y_1,x_2+y_2, x_2+y_3. \tag{1}
$$

Intuitively, I think it's all possible combinations is $m \cdot n$. I made the operation table (for the operation $+$) for some particular cases of $m$ and $n$ and I was able to conclude $m\cdot n$ possibilities. But how to prove this for the general case?

Comment: By combinations, are you talking about the value of the sum,  or just the form?  If it's the form,  you have just the image of the cross product under the + operator.   The # of values of the sums could be much less than that, depending on collisions

Comment: @Alan The number of the sums which is possible to compose of the form $x_i+y_j$.

Comment: This clearly depends on the sets involved.  Please clarify your question.

Comment: For example:  suppose your sets are $\{0,1\}$ and $\{1,2\}$.  How many sums do you see in that case?

Comment: @Guilherme just take all the $x_i$'s and $y_i$'s to be (distinct) powers of $2$.

Comment: It is certainly possible to get $mn$ for some collections $x_i$ and $y_j$ but sometimes you will not get the full $mn$ (think of the case where $m =n$, and  $x_i = i, y_j=j$; in this case there are at most $n(n+1)/2$ since any sum with $i<j$ will be repeated when you swap the indices).

Comment: @User8128  Does this agree with $(1)$?

Comment: @lulu See $(1)$, please.

Comment: Well, if you really just meant formal sums (so that $1+0$ is distinct from $0+1$) then obviously the answer is $mn$. But the question doesn't suggest that this is what was meant.  Rather it seems to be asking "how many distinct real numbers can be formed in this manner?" and that answer clearly depends on  the given sets.

Comment: @Guilherme I’m not sure what you mean by “agree with.” Really all my comment is meant to demonstrate is that the answer to the question depends very much on the particular sets $x_i$ and $y_j$ so it will be difficult to say anything that applies in general.

Comment: @lulu And how to prove that is $m \cdot n$? Can you answer my question?

Comment: That's the definition of $m\times n$.  All you care about is the number of indices on the two sides.  There are $m$ choices for the first slot and $n$ for the second, so you just have an $m\times n$ array.  But, really, edit your post for clarity.  I don't think any reader would interpret the question you wrote the way you want it interpreted.

Comment: At most $mn$ distinct sums can be formed.  However simple examples show that you might have as few as $n+1$ *distinct* sums.  Consider $\{1,2\}$ and $\{3,4,5\}$, whose distinct sums are $\{4,5,6,7\}$.  In other words there can be duplicates when $1\lt m \le n$.

Comment: @hardmath Your first comment agrees with the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X:=\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ and $Y:=\{y_1,\ldots,y_m\}$, the goal is to find ${\rm Card}(X+Y)$ where $X+Y:=\{x+y,(x,y)\in X\times Y\}$. First of all, $(x,y)\mapsto x+y$ is a surjection from $X\times Y$ to $X+Y$ therefore ${\rm Card}(X+Y)\leqslant{\rm Card}(X\times Y)=nm$. On the other hand, suppose without loss of generality that $x_1<\ldots<x_n$ and $y_1<\ldots<y_m$, then $x_1+y_1<\ldots<x_n+y_1<x_n+y_2<\ldots<x_n+y_m$ and each of these elements are in $X+Y$, therfore ${\rm Card}(X+Y)\geqslant n+m-1$. To summarize,
$$ n+m-1\leqslant{\rm Card}(X+Y)\leqslant nm $$
These bounds are optimal because when $X=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and $Y=\{n,2n,\ldots,mn\}$, the map $(x,y)\mapsto x+y$ is one to one because if $x+y=x'+y'$, then $x-x'=y'-y$ where $|x-x'|\leqslant n-1$ and $|y-y'|\geqslant n$ if $x\neq x'$ and $y\neq y'$, therefore $x=x'$ or $y=y'$, which implies $x=x'$ and $y=y'$ thus ${\rm Card}(X+Y)=mn$. On the other hand, if $X=\{x_0,x_0+r,\ldots,x_0+(n-1)r\}$ and $Y=\{y_0,y_0+r,\ldots,y_0+(m-1)r\}$ then $X+Y=\{x_0+y_0+(i+j)r,0\leqslant i\leqslant n-1,0\leqslant j\leqslant m-1\}$. Since $\{i+j,0\leqslant i\leqslant n-1,0\leqslant j\leqslant m-1\}=\{0,\ldots,m+n-2\}$, we have ${\rm Card}(X+Y)=m+n-1$.